# Where to consume webservices in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, mvvm

Using Visual Studio 2012 I have added a service reference to a remote webservice. It is configured to use asynchronous calls. The application uses WPF with the MVVM pattern.

One model class is called `Projects` and exposes a property `ProjectList` which can be used in the view model. The `ProjectList` shall contain a list of projects which are retrieved from the service.

So far I call this service from the view model like this (actually it's invoked by a command):

```
Projects.ProjectList = proxy.getProjectList(username, password);
```

Yes, it works but from what I have learned the "business logic" should not be handled by the view model. So how and where would I call the service and set the model's `ProjectList` property when the view fires a command in the view model?

Comment: I usually put it into a class of it's own that is meant to handle data transactions, then use that class from the ViewModel. That way if my data layer ever changes, I only need to modify one layer instead searching through all my ViewModels for the data access code that needs updating.

Comment: @Rachel: Yes, that is also my understanding but would the data layer - or whatever one might call it - directly modify the model property? Or would the view model set it?

Comment: The data layer returns the Model object, not the Model's data. So `IProductsRepository.GetProducts()` would return a `List<Product>` :)

Answer (score 0):

Use dependency injection to pass in a polymorphic interface into your ViewModel.

In this interface define functions that will communicate with your web service(es) and implement this interface in a concrete object(s). Instantiate the concrete object you need depending on what service source you need to access and pass it into the ViewModel via the interface you defined.

This way you can easily achieve all the benefits of loose coupling and polymorphism...

For example:

```
public ProjectListViewModel(IProjectListServiceAgent sa)

public interface IProjectListServiceAgent
{
    GetProjectList(string userName, string password)
}


public SqlProjectListFetcher : IProjectListServiceAgent 
{
   GetProjectList(string userName, string password)
   {
       //Fetch project list using direct SQL server access.
   }
}

public WebServiceProjectListFetcher : IProjectListServiceAgent 
{
   GetProjectList(string userName, string password)
   {
       //Fetch project list using web service.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a dependency to the ViewModel to use the proxy, I prefer to use always synchronous code with an asynchrnous system so the proxy has the method proxy.GetCustomerList and you can use the async keyword or the TaskFactory.

I'm maintaining a little framework helper for MVVM to simply this task, in particular:

1. retrieving the DTO, single or list
2. convert to ViewModel using a custom mapper (AutoMapper also)
3. [optional] sort the list
4. [optional] execute a method after the completition

Is possible also to execute everything in a single thread for testing purpose changing the configuration

The source code (not realtime update) is here http://hyperionsdk.codeplex.com and the packages here http://nuget.org/packages/EyeSoft.Wpf.Facilities.

An example of the usage:

```
public ViewModelSorted(ServiceFactory<ICustomerService> customerServiceFactory)
{
    customerServiceFactory
        .Collection(this, x => CustomerCollection)
        .Sort(x => x.LastName)
        .Fill(x => x.GetCustomersWithTurnoverGreatherThan(0));
}
```